# Append a sanitized glob() directory-only list to a php variable when onClick()'ed and reload AJAX div using new directory path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue figuring out how to append a sanitized string retrieved from a glob() directory listing to a variable when a div(made to look like a button, but not actually a button) is clicked, and then have AJAX reload the div with the new directory listing.

The idea is to write $dirPath from backend.php to $currentDir in index.php. (I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong way but I've only been doing this for two months, sorry :p )

I think it would be easier to understand after taking a look at the code. Let me know if you have any questions and thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. I apologize for any misuse or abuse of terminology :]

Here is the index.php page

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".buttons").click(function(event){

          $('#dirListing').load('backend.php');
      });
   });
   </script>


</head>
<body>
     <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="centerButtons">
           <div id="dirListing"> 
                <?php
                $currentDir = "";
                if($currentDir == ""){
                  $directories = glob("repository/*" , GLOB_ONLYDIR);  
                }
                else {$directories = glob("repository/*" , GLOB_ONLYDIR).$currentDir;}

                include_once 'backend.php';







                        ?>

           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

and here is the backend.php page:

```
<body>
<?php 





   foreach($directories as $result) {
                        $dirPath = str_replace(' ','%20',($result));
                        //echo $dirPath;

                        $dirName = basename($result);
                            echo '<div class="buttons" id ="buttonClick">';
                            echo $dirName;
                            echo '</div>';}

                        echo '<br class="clearBoth" /> ';
                        //print_r ($directories) ;
                        //print_r ($currentDir);


                            ?>

 </body>
```